# b1 button doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-button

I wrote a code and I can't understand why the button b1 does not work. Please help me identify the reason. I want mediaplayer mpAlbum to play right after mediaplayer mpChoose if the button b1 is clicked. But nothig happens after Mediaplayer mpChoose finishes playing, althogh the button b1 is clicked

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button b1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final MediaPlayer mpChoose = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.choose);
    final MediaPlayer mpLetIt = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.letit);
    final MediaPlayer mpAlbum = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.single);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.album);

    mpLetIt.start();
    mpLetIt.setNextMediaPlayer(mpChoose);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mpChoose.setNextMediaPlayer(mpAlbum);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Thank you for attention!

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: Do you try debugger to know if you pass though onClick ? If so, then your button works.

Comment: "does not work" is the *least* descriptive way you can tell us about a problem. We're not mind readers so please tell us in detail what the actual problem is.

Comment: Please read about [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As others have indicated, "doesn't work" isn't an actual problem description. Please also see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: What is `mpAlbum` and where do you set it?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I deleted it's set up accidentally, now it's back in it's right place.

Comment: Changed the statement of the problem, but I think that it's still not a good one. I'm going to revise some material and remake the question or delete it.

Comment: Does it actually start playing music?

Comment: @EJoshuaS mpAlbum is a Mediaplayer. So it's an object that controls audio playback. mpAlbum  should be played after mpChoose finishes, but it does not

Comment: @EJoshuaS Yes it plays mpLetIt and mpChoose, but mpAlbum, which is optional to play and should be playd if the button is clicked, is not played

Comment: Does the Event Handler definitely run?

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, what happens if you move `mpAlbum` to be a field instead of a local variable?

Comment: @EJoshuaS The app fails to launch then for some reasons

Comment: Does the event handler definitely run?

Comment: Hi...Can you share your xml? Is your button visible and top of all views? Can you make sure?

Comment: @Aditi Parikh Hi! I have just came here to tell that the problem is solved and then saw your comment. The problem really was that the button was invisible and there was an ImageView upon it. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Great...Glad that the problem is solved..

Answer (score 0):

Try to display a Toast or a log inside the onClick method to see if it's really the button which doesn't work or not, if it works for them, try to declare your MediaPlayer as global variables.

Comment: I inserted a Toast and nothing popped out, so the button doesnt work

Comment: If I declare  MediaPlayers as global variables in this code, for some reason the app would give me a messege 'Unfortunately, <app name> has stopped'

Comment: try to remove or comment out all the mediaplayers, and make another button, that's really strange.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in xml. The button was invisible and there was an ImageView upon it. Now the button works properly.